# In which scenarios it's better to use a multi-step wizard / workflow?

Tags: workflow, wizard, multi-step

What are the guidelines to understand if a "flat" configuration screen should be used or a multi-step wizard/workflow?

In my app I have 2 groups of multi-selection settings and a file that should be uploaded. The settings are mutually independent. Upon creation, each of the settings (i.e. the file or the multi-selections) can be modified.

Should I make a 3-steps flow (a step per multi-selection and another step for the file upload) or a configuration screen. Each multi-selection can contain lots of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (user needs to upload a file, with two sets of settings available in the process), I think one screen with accordion for each set of settings should suffice, unless any of the sets is complex or contains more than 2 controls.

As for the more generic question when to use wizards, as put by the timeless classic of Jenifer Tidwell's "Designing Interfaces",

> [Use a wizard when] You are designing a UI for a task that is long or complicated, and that will usually be novel for users—not something that they do often or want much fine-grained control over (such as the installation of a software package). You’re reasonably certain that the designer of the UI will know more than the user does about how best to get the task done.
>
> Tasks that seem well suited for this approach tend to be either
>   branched or very long and tedious—they consist of a series of
>   user-made decisions that affect downstream choices.
>
> The catch is that the user must be willing to surrender control over
>   what happens when. In many contexts, that works out fine, since making
>   decisions is an unwelcome burden for people doing certain things:
>   “Don’t make me think, just tell me what to do next.” Think about
>   moving through an unfamiliar airport—it’s often easier to follow a
>   series of signs than it is to figure out the airport’s overall
>   structure. You don’t get to learn much about how the airport is
>   designed, but you don’t care about that.
>
> But in other contexts, it backfires. Expert users often find wizards
>   frustratingly rigid and limiting. This is particularly true for
>   software that supports creative processes such as writing, art, or
>   coding. It’s also true for users who actually do want to learn the
>   software; wizards don’t show users what their actions really do, or
>   what application state gets changed as choices are made. That can be
>   infuriating to some people.

http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/wizard/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in order to develop a wizard style solution your categories have to be clear and consistent.

**For example** : *Select product* / *Personal Details* / *Pay* (3 Straightforward and clear steps)

If you think that you can divide your input values in steps, without user get confused, go for it!